# In Python, how can I pass a non-int argument to a function that expects an int argument and get my own error message

Tags: python, function, error-handling, try-except

I want to produce my error message, not the system one when I pass something that is not an int to a function that expects an int.

I tried all kinds of ways to do this: exceptions, assertions, testing statements for type is int, but nothing seems to work. What I always get is the system-generated message of “syntax error”

Is there any way I can override the system message, or add to it?

My best hope was

```python
def square(n):
   try:
     m=int(n)          
     return m**2
   except Exception as error:
     print(' argument to square() must be an int ' + str(error))
```

But even that doesn’t work. Is there some way to get what I want, or will I have to accept the system generated error as in?

```
square(5z)
  File "<ipython-input-6-0a289452c433>", line 1
    square(5z)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. You cannot call `square(5z)`. Maybe you want `square(5 * z)`.

Comment: Also, please be aware that Python is sensitive to indentation. Your ln 3 and ln 4 must be indented with the same number of spaces.

Comment: try pydantic , you can define your own custom error message there and check the type of input objects

Comment: `5z` is not a valid Python token, so it's a syntax error.  Your file won't even compile into byte code if you have a syntax error (nor would you want it to), so you have no control over that error.  You can control dynamic error checks to some extent, but not static ones.  I suppose you could use `importlib`, and wrap the import in a `try` statement, giving your own error if the import fails, but I don't see much advantage to that.

Answer (score 1):

python assertion is really useful

```
def square(n):
  is_integer = isinstance(n,int)
  assert is_integer,"input must be integer"
  return m**2
```

or, in one line,

```
def square(n):
  assert isinstance(n,int),"input must be integer"
  return m**2
```

please accept my answer if it was helpful!

Comment: I have both python 3.8.5 and 3.7.11, but in neither version does your assert version produce the "input must be integer" message. I always get the syntax error. Also notice that the 3rd line should be return n**2, for it to work when an int is passed.

Comment: okay. see <https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_assert.asp> on the assert keyword. i think that you will need python 3.9+

Answer (score 0):

what makes you think your suggested code does not work?

https://onlinegdb.com/S0vbrhGpF

it is probably more common to catch only `ValueError` that you expect, rather than every exception.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it should be a comment.

Comment: @richard I had previously tried what you suggest but I get "syntax error" in a standard interpreter.  Your onlineGDB is some kind of non-standard interpreter, so even though you got what I would like, that doesn't happen in standard environments. I think Tom Karzes has the right answer: namely that it's not possible to catch a syntax error. This is what I suspected, but wanted to run it by people that know more than me.

Comment: I did not suggest the code, it is the code from your example with common indentation. it behaves in the online python and a standard python install just the same, as intended. your interpreter is non-standard or you are calling it in an invalid way.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your argument to function Square(5).
You can even use assert to override the system errors.